# django project root self discovery

Tags: django

Ok so I recall there are some commands you could put in the `settings.py` file so that basically when you move your django project to another directory it won't get foo-bar'd up.

I know I could just do this by having a string variable everywhere it mentions the home directory but is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: Thanks to Ignacio for the quick response, from it I was able to find this tutorial for those who need a fuller explanation. http://morethanseven.net/2009/02/11/django-settings-tip-setting-relative-paths.html

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Grab the `__file__` global, and use the various functions in `os.path` on it.

```
import os.path
SITE_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

Comment: It's very useful to create a lambda function where you can use the SITE_ROOT-variable later: rel = lambda p: os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, p) You can use it like: MEDIA_ROOT = rel('static_media')

Comment: Do not assign lambda to a variable. Use def instead.

Answer (score 109):

The architecture of a project in Django

- root/

  - app1/
  - app2/
  - ...
  - main/

    - settings.py

*Inside settings.py:*

`SITE_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))` -> gives the path of the file settings.py: *root/main/*. This is **NOT THE ROOT OF THE PROJECT**

`PROJECT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__name__))` -> gives the root of the project: *root/*. This is **THE ROOT OF THE PROJECT**.

Comment: This is an old question, django's file structure was different at the time. How did you find this anyway? :) Also it was being depricated at the time I asked it as well. But thanks. I'll +1 you since you provide new info.

Comment: I'll +1 for this because he explained **WHY** we do this.

Comment: How does `os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__name__))` work? `__name__` is [the name of the current module](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html?highlight=__name__#__name__). Doing `dirname` of that gives an empty string, and doing `abspath` of that empty string gives the current working dir, which for the author of the post was conveniently the root of the project, but that's just a coincidence.

Answer (score 72):

Django 1.8 already includes the project root directory as `BASE_DIR`:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

And you can use it in your app by importing `settings`:

```
from django.conf import settings
...
...
print(settings.BASE_DIR)
```

Answer (score 16):

```
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__name__))
```

Comment: How does `os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__name__))` work? `__name__` is [the name of the current module](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html?highlight=__name__#__name__). Doing `dirname` of that gives an empty string, and doing `abspath` of that empty string gives the current working dir, which for the author of the post was conveniently the root of the project, but that's just a coincidence.