# Get absolute path of django app

Tags: django, django-settings

I am writing a unit test that needs to access an image file that I put in "fixtures" directory right under my django app directory. I want to open up this image file in my test using relative path, which would require me to get the absolute path of the django app. Is there a way to get the absolute path of the django app?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Python modules (including Django apps) have a `__file__` attribute that tells you the location of their `__init__.py` file on the filesystem, so

```
import appname
pth = os.path.dirname(appname.__file__)
```

should do what you want.

In usual circumstances, `os.path.absname(appname.__path__[0])`, but it's possible for apps to change that if they want to import files in a weird way.

(I do always do `PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` in my `settings.py`, though -- makes it easy for the various settings that need to be absolute paths.)

Comment: This is not actually correct because appname.__path__ is list, not a string. See http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages-in-multiple-directories

Comment: @GeorgeLund You're right, of course; silly of me. You could do `appname.__path__[0]`, though it seems like it's possible to change that; you could also use `os.path.dirname(appname.__file__)`, since `__file__` points to the `__init__.py` file.

Comment: Can you change your answer to match your comment  because the answer is what most people see first.

Comment: @Igor Sure, changed it.

Comment: Note that now Django provides settings.BASE_DIR, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32156582/1104244

Comment: @DirkBergstrom: That doesn't help if you have an app installed via pip, and you need files of *that* installation in site-packages.

Answer (score 20):

So the accepted answer usually works fine. However, for

- namespace packages with multiple paths, or
- apps which explicitly configure their paths in the config,

their intended path may not agree with the `__file__` attribute of the module.

Django (1.7+) provides the [`AppConfig.path`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.path) attribute - which I think is clearer even in simple cases, and which covers these edge cases too.

[The application docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/applications/) tell you how to get the AppConfig object. So to get AppConfig and print the path from it:

```
from django.apps import apps
print(apps.get_app_config('app_label').path)
```

Edit:
Altered example for how to use `get_app_config` to remove dots, which seems to have been confusing. [Here are the docs for reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/applications/#django.apps.apps.get_app_config).

Comment: Also worth noting, the accepted answer also won't work in settings either, as it requires import of the app. If you find an elegant way to do this in settings, @RobM, it'll be worth posting it! :)

Comment: Also to mention, get_app_config() needs an app_label (e.g. "foo"), not the app's `name` (e.g. namespace.baz.foo). This makes it a bit more complicated if there are 2 labels named "foo" in different namespaces...

Comment: BTW: passing the dotted name to `get_app_config()` raises an LookupError, so this answer is not really a good one.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because it uses native Django, without the need for importing the third party library "appname".

Answer (score 15):

Normally, this is what I add in my settings.py file so I can reference the project root.

```
import os.path

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

This method will get the directory of any python file.

Comment: That's smart, but it gives the path to the project not to the app. In my case, it's gonna work fine because, in the filesystem, my app lives under the project, otherwise it would not make. Is there any way I can actually get the path to the app? Or is this the closest that I can get?

Comment: You could use it within a file that happens to be in the app, or append the path to the app within the folder to the PROJECT_ROOT using os.path.join()

Comment: Btw, you have misplaced `abspath` and `dirname`. Should have been the other way around.

Comment: @ahmoo You can also get the app path by `import appname; os.path.abspath(appname.__path__)`.

Comment: @Dougal - thanks. `appname.__path__` is exactly what I am looking for. Add your comment as a solution and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5):

În newer versions of Django (I don't know when it started, I assume it's there for many years now), the default settingy.py contains an entry

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

which you can use by importing the settings file like this

```
import os    
from my_project_name.settings import BASE_DIR

os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Python3.4 and above comes with standard library `pathlib`.

```
from pathlib import Path
import appmodule

pth = Path(appmodule.__file__).parent / 'fixtures'
if pth.exists():
     "Your code here"
```

`parent` will give you the path of your app directory, and `/` will append fixtures as path.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that `appname.__path__` is a list:

```
import appname
APP_ROOT = os.path.abspath(appname.__path__[0])
file_path = os.path.join(APP_ROOT, "some_file.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

Django auto-generated setting file has the following that you can use as well

> BASE_DIR = Path(**file**).resolve().parent.parent