# django - Use static files in method

Tags: django

I have a project with two apps, one is the website called 'web' and the other is called 'tools' which are a collection of tools for the admin/users.

What I want to do is to scan a folder of images in the web app from a method in the tools app. The images are in the static folder of web:

```
/web/static/web/images/
```

How can I get to this folder from the tools folder?

Here is what I have tried:

```
files = []
fileRoots = []
#path = STATIC_ROOT + 'web/images/'
for root, directories, filenames in os.walk(STATIC_IMAGES):#probably something wrong with the location
    for filename in filenames:
        files.append(os.path.join(root,filename))            
        fileRoots.append(root)
```

Also in the projects folder I have:

```
STATIC_IMAGES = '/web/static/web/images/'
```

How can I access these images?

Comment: You probably want to join (check Python's `os.path.join` function) the base path with STATIC_IMAGES path before walking into it.

Comment: @HerberthAmaral do you mean the base path of the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this useful:

[Get absolute path of django app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847911/get-absolute-path-of-django-app)

Here is what I did:

```
import tools, web

pth = web.__path__[0] + "/static/web/images"#os.path.join(tools.__path__,"static/web/images")
for root, directories, filenames in os.walk(pth):#probably something wrong with the location
    for filename in filenames:
        files.append(os.path.join(root,filename))            
        fileRoots.append(root)
```