# What is the path for TEMPLATE_DIRS in django settings.py when using virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv

I am using virtualenv and I want to know what the `TEMPLATE_DIRS` in `settings.py` should be, for example if I make a templates folder in the root of my project folder.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to specify the absolute path to your template folder. Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.

For example, if your project folder is "/home/djangouser/projects/myproject" (Linux) or 'C:\projects\myproject\' (Windows), your TEMPLATE_DIRS looks like this:

```
    # for Linux
    TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
        '/home/djangouser/projects/myproject/templates/',
    )

    # or for Windows; use forward slashes!
    TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
        'C:/projects/myproject/templates/',
    )
```

Alternatively you can use the specified PROJECT_ROOT variable and generate the absolute path by joining it with the relative path to your template folder. This has the advantage that you only need to change your PROJECT_ROOT, if you copy the project to a different location. You need to import the os module to make it work:

```
# add at the beginning of settings.py
import os

# ...

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'templates/'),
)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Its saying PROJECT_ROOT not defined for the second answer.

Comment: my project folder is at /Users/andrewwelch/Sites/env/ and I presume I would have to change this if I put it onto a remote server

Comment: Yeah, my fault. I noticed that PROJECT_ROOT is not a standard variable and was added by me to the settings.py I looked up. It's basically the same like the suggestions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919600/django-project-root-self-discovorey

Comment: thanks for that. is there any way to test what that PROJECT_ROOT variable is returning?

Comment: I can do that with the python shell. Thanks.

Comment: @eminor any clue as to why we use forward slashes even on windows?  Is this so code is more portable to non-windows platforms?

Answer (score 16):

If you're working with a newer version of Django you may have to add it to the DIR list that is inside settings.py under TEMPLATES.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['[project name]/templates'], # Replace with your project name
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: `'DIRS': ['[project name]/templates'], # Replace with your project name` project name without brockets: `'project name/templates'`

Comment: The bracket is there to symbolize where you input your specific project name.

Answer (score 3):

the PROJECT_DIR has not been defined... the PROJECT_DIR is not a variable. its a directory/ a path to where the folder "templates" is located. This should help

```
import os
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
TEMPLATE_DIRS = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'templates')
```

Comment: The `TEMPLATE_DIRS` setting must be a list or a tuple.

Answer (score 2):

> **TEMPLATE_DIRS** deprecated
> This setting is deprecated since Django version 1.8.

`deprecated`

```
""" settings.py """

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates/'),
)
```

`correct`

```
""" settings.py """

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [ os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates') ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        ...
    },
]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Django 1.9, it is recommended to use BASE_DIR instead of PROJECT_DIR.

```
# add at the beginning of settings.py
import os

# ...

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates/'),
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Adding this in web/settings.py  solved everything for me. Hope it can help you too.

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
from os.path import join
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    join(BASE_DIR,  'templates'),
)
```

Comment: How is this any different from the already posted answers? All you did was bind `join` as a global rather than use the full `os.path.join()` spelling.

Comment: when i used the already posted answers . i could get an error saying BASE_DIR is not found

Comment: `BASE_DIR` is just a name (although it looks like the project template in Django 1.9 and up define the name now, see https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/conf/project_template/project_name/settings.py-tpl). [What is the path for TEMPLATE\_DIRS in django settings.py when using virtualenv](//stackoverflow.com/a/24706023) used the name `PROJECT_DIR` for the exact same value however.