# TEMPLATE_DIRS is missing in settings.py (django 1.6)

Tags: django

I am reading http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter04.html which follows Django 1.4 but I use Django 1.6 so how to set the template directory in Django 1.6 as settings.py doesn’t have TEMPLATE_DIRS variable and why the developers changed this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps the answer here. https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/12493

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Add to settings.py

```
from os.path import join
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    join(BASE_DIR,  'templates'),
)
```

Comment: Do you know why they changed it?

Answer (score 5):

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,  'templates'),
)
```

Add this to `settings.py`. In django 1.6 `BASE_DIR` is defined. Otherwise define `BASE_DIR` as

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

Answer (score 3):

According to Django tutorial, you should add
`TEMPLATE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]`
to your *settings.py* file (so it is a `list` not a `tuple`)

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,  'templates'),
)
```

Or you might see an error like this :

> DeprecationWarning: The TEMPLATE_DIRS setting must be a tuple. Please
>   fix your settings, as auto-correction is now deprecated.
>   self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)

For django >= 1.6 it is a `tuple`

Answer (score 1):

Use the below given code snippet. Paste it in last of the settings.py file.

```
from os.path import join
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    join(BASE_DIR,  'templates'),
)
```

Here `BASE_DIR` means your project directory, not the inner directory where the settings.py resides. Create a directory named "templates" (without quotes) inside the `BASE_DIR` and store your templates inside that directory. Django will join templates directory to the `BASE_DIR` using `os.path.join()` function. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

As I posted https://stackoverflow.com/a/40145444/6333418 you have to add it to the DIR list that is inside settings.py under TEMPLATES.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['[project name]/templates'], # Replace with your project name
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```