# import models in django without specify the complete path

Tags: python, django

I would can import my models in django, without having to specify the complete path at moment.
For example:

In my admin.py I have:

```
from django.contrib import admin 
from project.app.models import *   

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Model_A)
admin.site.register(Model_B)
```

I want import my models of this way (in the second import):

```
from django.contrib import admin 
from models import * 

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Model_A)
admin.site.register(Model_B)
```

Is it necessary to fix some settings? Are these dependent on the IDE or tool that I am using?

Comment: Don't do this. Other developers will want to kill you, and eventually you'll want to do the same.

Comment: Of course, I know that this is bad practice. At moment I'm trying fix this with the order of don't put the absolute path. Any recommendation is appreciated.

Comment: My recommendation is that you asked whoever ordered you to do this just how badly they want the project broken.

Comment: I don't think so. It's a problem or paths, I'm looking in my settings.py file with the directive import os.path
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) ... but I'm not sure. Thanks for the support.

Comment: Seem that the problem is in my IDE configuration (I'm working with PyCharm-3.1). from models import *  works instead of from project.app.models import *  but the strange is that the models are not recognize in the IDE. I think that is download problem at moment of install the models packages for the IDE operation ..   as shown in this figure https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4780771/models.jpg

Comment: Because when I run my application, this is deployed good https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4780771/admin-panel.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can use sys path:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('the path of your project')
from django.contrib import admin 
from models import * 

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Model_A)
admin.site.register(Model_B)
```

Comment: Mohamed, thanks. But, How to interpret the path of my project? In this question, talk about of differences between PROJECT_PATH and PROJECT_ROOT http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919600/django-project-root-self-discovery  but I don't finish of understand this.

Answer (score 0):

apparently there is a problem of interpreter configuration in my settings. I'solved this.
Thanks.