# Unknown statement type in Django

Tags: python, django

I am new in Python and i am studying this code. I am trying to figure out what is the meaning of the terms like `PROJECT_ROOT` i suspect it is something like an event. I have imported the os in the GUI but when i searched the term by typing `help(os)` i did not find it in there

```
#Django settings for pysec project
import os

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': '',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        # The following settings are not used with sqlite3:
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',                      # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default.
    }
}
```

I 've searched many tutorials from python site and the documentation but i did not find the meaning of these commands.

*I've searched other words in os also like ADMINS and DEBUG*

Comment: It's a variable like any other. All Caps in Python implies that the variable is a constant.

Comment: That means they are `immutable` ?

Comment: They are not `immutable`, as python doesn't really support immutability natively, but they should be treated as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of code can look intimidating, but the only purpose of code like this is to define some project-wide constants that you can use where ever you want. You could set your own constants if you like and nothing would break, they just would be used, like so:

```
import os

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

MY_VARIABLE = "nonsense"
```

The only point is so that elsewhere (assuming the above file is named `settings.py`) you can write something like this:

```
from settings import PROJECT_ROOT
```

or

```
import settings
print settings.PROJECT_ROOT
```

Specifically, `PROJECT_ROOT` is a path to the current file, `DEBUG` is really just a boolean set to `True`, `TEMPLATE_DEBUG` is then also set to that same boolean (`True`), and so on and so forth.

The definition of these constants is simple, the complicated parts are what Django actually does with these constants when it comes time to use them. If you want to understand that, you have to dig into some django source code.

Answer (score 1):

All your questions are answered in the docs, [available here on the Django site](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/settings/). You should read the Django tutorial before proceeding or you'll get stuck on every single feature of Django!

Answer (score 1):

`os` is a module in the Python standard library, see [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html). `os.path` is a submodule, see [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html).

`__file__` is a path to the current file (the Python file this code is in, probably `"./settings.py"` or so).

`os.path.dirname` takes a path and returns the directory part of it (the path minus `settings.py`).

`os.path.abspath` turns a path into an absolute path.

`PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))` makes the setting "PROJECT_ROOT" equal to the absolute path of the directory that settings.py is in.

`settings.py` contains perfectly normal Python code that is executed when Django starts up, Django imports variables from it and that's how you configure Django.

Comment: Most of this is pure Python though, not Django. You need to know some Python first.

Answer (score 0):

`PROJECT_ROOT` is Django magic, normally you don't need to worry about it. You can see that Django skeleton code dynamically infers it from the path of current Python source file.

I think it's used to find own resources (e.g. static images) once this code is deployed.

Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/16413955/705086

Comment: I really want to understand this code in depth so i need to learn Django right?

Comment: The code above is far from Django magic. It's just setting some constants, Django does magic with it though.

Comment: If you use Django a lot, sure go ahead and learn it :) I'm trying to stay away from this beast