# Python: Module and file with the same name

Tags: python, django, python-import

This is my Django project folder structure

```
/
 |
 --some_name
    |
    --lib
 |
 --another_name
    |
    --another_lib
       |
       --some_name.py
```

The problem occuer when I run a code from:

```
another_name/another_lib/some_name.py
```

When I try to load the upper lib some_name/lib

```
import some_name.lib
```

I get:

```
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value: No module named some_name.lib
```

python doesn't find it and it tries to load:

```
another_name.another_lib.some_name.lib
```

How can I make it load the other package without changing the search path each time?
Can I make python search from the root of my folder structure ?

Comment: Ensure Python is able to [find your modules (hint: `sys.path`)](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#import). I think the [following SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919600/django-project-root-self-discovery) might also be of some help to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python 2, it first tries to import a module relative to the current module. This implicit relative import has been removed in Python 3.

To use the new behaviour in Python 2, put this at the top of your file:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```