# Django not loading style file from static directry

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I am facing a strange issue with the Django application on my local, the file is available in the static directory.

The following is in the settings.py

```
STATIC_ROOT = SITE_ROOT + '/static/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

this is how I am trying to include style file

```
<link href="/static/msc.css?v=1.2" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

the following is added in urls.py

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

The file exist in the static directory, but it is not loading, I am facing a 404 error in console for the URL: http://localhost:8000/static/msc.css?v=1.2

please help me in this regard thanks.

Comment: What is your `STATICFILES_DIRS`?

Comment: I highly recommend you to look through the official django tutorials https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial06/

Comment: take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919600/django-project-root-self-discovery and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66437690/django-html-template-cant-find-static-css-and-js-files/66439076#66439076

Comment: please also note that in my case only this style sheet is not being loaded rest of the things are loading properly

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing things the Django way.

When working with static files in Django

a) you need to use {% load static %} at the very beginning of your template

b) The link to static file is created using the following pattern

```
<link href="{% static 'path/to/style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Suppose that I have a directory in my django project static/css/style.css, then

```
<link href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```